# How to use two ethernet ports on the wall with one ethernet port on PC?

Tags: networking, ethernet

I have a single 1Gbps ethernet port on my PC. There are two ethernet ports on the wall of my dorm, each throttled to 100Mbps.

Is there any way for me to use both wall ports at once to achieve (theoretically) 200Mbps bandwidth? Searches only come up with solutions to plug 2 ports on the *PC* into a single port on the wall.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution will be to get a
[Multi-WAN router](https://techgenix.com/multi-wan-routers/).

However, the main benefit of such a router will be Internet load balancing,
so being able to distribute all connections on the two lines.
The speed of each connection by itself will stay 100Mbps.

This setup can also cause unexpected problems.
For a real-world experience, see
[Will a multi-wan router double my speed](https://www.speedguide.net/faq/will-a-multi-wan-router-double-my-speed-420)
where such a setup was actually less efficient for doing torrents.

The cost of this setup might not be worth the possible gain.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but it is unlikely you will get your full 200 megabits of throughput.

You will need a gigabit switch (maybe a vlan switch depending on configuration of the upstream and then plug your laptop into it, as well as both jacks. You then need to configure the load balancing and IP address(es), and/or handle routing. The exact howto agaon depends on your OS and how the upstream is configured.

Alternatively you can get load balancing routers which may facilitate this at a router level - again, setup depends on the upstream. (Google "load balancong routers").  This is likely a simpler route, although often more applicable to networks then single PCs - again depending on the upstream and load balancing mechanism.

Regardless of your OS, it may be worthwhile reading https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/overview-of-bonding-modes-and-the-required-settings-on-the-switch to get a better understanding of the various ways to do bonding and the limitations of each.